# How to calculate β from this circuit?

Tags: control-system

[image: feedback system]

I try to derive the transfer function from the Bode plot. I get UGF as 106. Phase margin is around -90° (-270°+180°).

Now the question here in image 3. How to find β in this? After that, how to proceed to find the phase margin?

[image: Transfer function of the system]

[image: what is beta?]

Comment: I do not understand the phase plot. Question: The magnitude plot shows the open-loop gain. But is there any relation to the shown phase plot? Wen the magnitude drops by 20dB/dek, the corresponding phase must be - more or less - in the minus 90 deg region, Why does the phase reaches -270 deg? That is a 3rd-order phase shift!!

Comment: @LvW There is a RHZ which cancel out one LHP, cant be seen in magnitude plot but can be observed in phase plot. Thats why you get 180 degree

Comment: I must confess that I did not look at the handwritten parts of your question. I was a bit lazy - and it is bad to read.

Comment: I rewrote my answer completely, I was too fast (and wrong) in writing it.

Comment: I don't get your question. All your graphs are showing are the magnitude and argument of the forward transfer function H(s). This doesn't say anything about the feedback network β. You should present also the transfer function of the closed loop system.

Comment: @Bart of course it does. Beta=1 in the plots.

Comment: Ah yes, I see now. The very small text in question 16. It wasn't really clear from the question.

Comment: @Bart even if it wasn't in that text, the open-loop gain bode plot is equivalent to saying that the beta=1.

Comment: @ErnestoG I don't agree. It is explicitly stated that the Bode plot is from the forward path H(s), not the open-loop gain H(s)β with β equal to unity. I just overlooked that the 90 degrees phase margin is a requirement of the assignment.

Comment: @Bart yeah I misunderstood what you misunderstood haha. I also almost asked the same question you asked, but then realized that it was about sizing for phase margin.

Answer (score 3):

For the loop transmission to have a phase margin of 0° (Basically, where the loop makes a full -180° phase, or it becomes -1), we need the UGF to be at 100kHz. This would imply a dB(beta) = -20dB = 0.1. We have to get rid of the excessive phase shift.

However, the questions asks for a 90° phase margin. Therefore, this means that we would need the cross-over frequency to be at 10kHz, because, at that point, the phase is -90°. At that point, we need at least -40dB = 0.01 = k, as you correctly stated before (and I was wrong). So this is the right answer.

Comment: you are giving insight, I believe answer is 0.01. (I didnt get insight on how it is done)

I didnt get how you took -180 as reference. We have -270 degree at UGC. can you explain a bit more.
@ErnestoG

Comment: May be i think, at -90, we have gain as 40dB, which we need to reduce from the open loop gain . so it could be 60-40dB, which will give the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my results (confirmed by simulation):

1.) For 100% feedback we have 0dB loop gain at w=1E6 rad/s and the loop phase is at -260deg. This indicates **instability**.

2.) At w=1E5 rad/s the loop phase is -180deg and the loop gain is +20dB. Hence, the **stability limit** (0 dB) is reached when the feedback factor **beta=-20dB (0.1)**.

3.) At w=7*1E3 rad/s (approximately) the loop phase is -90deg with a loop gain of app. 42.5dB. Therefore, the feedback factor for a **margin of 90 deg** must be beta=-42.5 dB equivalent to a **factor 0.0075**.

Comment: I also got that from exact calculation, but given the answer options, one can say that using bode's approximations are good enough.

Comment: Yes - the Bode plot contains exactly the same information as the Nyquist plot. It is just a separate presentation of the magnitude and the phase.

Answer (score 0):

Hum, very weird in fact ...

This is a simulation to help ...

[image]

[image]

"Open loop" Nyquist chart ( 0.5m < beta < 3m, stepping 0.5m).
[For reference](https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Nyquist/NyquistStability.html)
Some [examples](https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Nyquist/NyquistExamples.html) ...

[image]

Comment: feel system would be unstable if you use transfer funciton of what I derived, I have a doubt, how you simulated it. I didnt get what you are trying to do, but this gives good intuition on what happens

Comment: Show "stable" output for beta=0.001. Will add Nyquist diagram.

Comment: they dont want stability, rather answer. right answer is 0.01. I also found a way to do it

Comment: Ok for that answer ... Just showed that for beta=0.002, system was stable.